# Pivot data in Talend

Tags: talend

I have some data which I need to pivot in Talend. This is a sample:

```
brandname,metric,value
A,xyz,2
B,xyz,2
A,abc,3
C,def,1
C,ghi,6
A,ghi,1
```

Now I need this data to be pivoted on the metric column like this:

```
brandname,abc,def,ghi,xyz
A,3,null,1,2
B,null,null,null,2
C,null,1,6,null
```

Currently I am using tPivotToColumnsDelimited to pivot the data to a file and reading back from that file. However having to store data on an external file and reading back is messy and unnecessary overhead.

Is there a way to do this with Talend without writing to an external file? I tried to use tDenormalize but as far as I understand, it will return the rows as 1 column which is not what I need. I also looked for some 3rd party component in TalendExchange but couldn't find anything useful.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Exactly, but isn't that the definition of a pivot? You turn rows into columns, and the values associated with those rows are assigned accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your metrics are fixed, you can use their names as columns of the output. The solution to do the pivot has two parts: first, a `tMap` that transposes the value of each input-row `in` into the corresponding column in the output-row `out` and second, a `tAggregate` that groups the map's output-rows according to the brandname.

For the tMap you'd have to fill the columns conditionally like this, example for output colum named "abc":
`out.abc = "abc".equals(in.metric)?in.value:null`

In the `tAggregate` you'd have to group by `out.brandname` and aggregate each column as sum ignoring nulls.