# Talend Pivoting and save data into another table

Tags: pivot, talend

In my job I need to save the result of my pivoting into another table:

[image]

The problem is that I don't know how to save the result in my WK1_SF_SRV_TASK table. The output in the .csv file is correct, but how can I instead use the result to fill the table? I don't know how to connect them to do this.

This table has exactly the columns that I have as a result in the excel file. 
I've found a question with the same problem, but there was only one answer that I didn't understand at all (and that was not considered correct). [This is the question I'm referring to.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978766/pivot-data-in-talend)

Answer (score 0):

The question you refer to has shown that the pivot is saved as a CSV to a file, and the user is then re-reading that file to use it, and they don't like doing that (which I wholeheartedly understand).

The problem Talend has with a pivot like this, is that Talend uses a fixed number of columns in row2 in your diagram, and if you wanted to create a row3 from your pivot to the database output unit, it would need a fixed number of columns.

However, the pivot doesn't have a fixed number of columns. When you look at your quoted question, it works for him because his source data has the right data to create the number of columns he wants, but what if you had a variable number of columns? That is why the component only writes a CSV to file, because each row can have a variable number of columns dependent on the input data.

In this instance, if you know the columns you will get from the pivot are what you want in your database, read the CSV file produced by the pivot and write to your database, linking the two subjobs with `onSubjobOK`.

Alternatively, you could use tDenormalize as the other question suggested, and then break the denormalized column in to the columns you want using tExtractDelimitedFields.